# CPU Usage to 100%

Tags: sql, oracle11g, cpu-usage

I have Oracle 11G R2 running on M-4000 machine (supposedly a powerful machine). Recently, I noticed that my application has gone slow and is taking lot of time in quering from database. To my shock when I saw the statistics of DB machine I found the CPU usage to 100%.

[Here](https://picasaweb.google.com/chevalier51/March22012?authkey=Gv1sRgCMjIzInF3sXssAE#5715360392626499922) is the ash report.

Now can someone put me wise to what should I be doing to avoid such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those queries that are doing a 'table access full' may be your problem...  any full table scan will kill a query and can usually be resolved by adding a simple index.  You can profile your queries, and tools will recommend indexes to add in order to improve execution of certain queries.  I think I did this with Squirrel on an oracle db.

Also, your IDs seem to be strings and you're doing a 'lower(id) like :3'.  This should be changed to use integers, or at the very least get rid of the lower and do a match on '3'.